# How to convert python3 csv representation as list to valid csv data using the `csv` module

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have such list:

```py
[["1", "2"], ["3", "4"], ["bacon", "eggs"]]
```

And I want to convert it to csv using
the `csv` module safely, so it'd look
something like this:

```
1,2
3,3
bacon,eggs
```

But I cannot find a way to do it, is there even
a way to do it? What should I use to do such thing,
I don't want to write it to a temporary file, I want
it to be all in-memory, for example how I parsed
it into a list in the first place:

```py
list(csv.reader(StringIO(data.decode())))
```

`StringIO` is from the `io` module

If it matters this application is for UNIX-like only

Thanks for the answers in advance :)

Comment: The "csv" module provides a "writer" function as well which accepts a StringIO object as file and the returned writer object has a "writerows" method to write the data of the nested list you have.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Hey, thanks for the answer! I appreciate it, although this topic has already been answered :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `StringIO` with `csv` module you can use  next example:

```py
import csv
from io import StringIO

data = [["1", "2"], ["3", "4"], ["bacon", "eggs"]]

with StringIO() as f_out:
    w = csv.writer(f_out)
    w.writerows(data)

    # print the contents of f_out:
    f_out.seek(0)
    print(f_out.read())
```

Prints:

```
1,2
3,4
bacon,eggs
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! Didn't think of it somehow